# How to turn a git feature branch into a parallel dev branch

Tags: git

I have a git branch management question.  I have a web based project that is using "git flow" branches: `main`, `develop`, `feature`, etc.  I currently have `main` and `develop` branches that are the result of the last "release".  I have a `feature` branch that is re-implementing the project using a "new technology".  I am on the verge of merging the feature branch back into the develop branch and creating a new main branch release.

However, a comment from a colleague has made me think about this in a different light.  The current "main branch" release of the project works on "older browsers".  The feature branch code probably only works on fairly recent browsers (1-3 years old).  I have now learned that there is yet a third method for doing this task that works on browsers of an intermediate age and all three overlap with browser versions at various points.

My colleague asked why we do not sense the browser version and present the version the "works best" for it?

So my question in this moment is how do I transform the current feature branch into a 2nd "development" branch that is unique to this "new" method

Comment: You can just keep running this branch. Renaming it to `develop2` or `develop_new` is optional. But when you are ready to release it, are going to create another release branch?

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev's comment. In the [Git Flow model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), the left most pink feature branch is an example of a long-running feature. You can name the branch whatever you'd like. If you are going to have multiple collaborators on it you may want to consider making it a specific name (like `develop2)` and protecting it, and then having multiple people PR into the branch so you can capture code reviews. If you do this you'll probably benefit from merging `develop` into `develop2` periodically so it doesn't fork too much.

Comment: Thank you both!  I wasn't thinking in this direction at all.